# Is there any way to "reinstantiate" an instance on Spring.net

Tags: c#, spring.net

I'm using a Service instantiated by a CustomFactory of [Spring.net](http://springframework.net/) that reads a configuration stored in database. Sometimes, an administrator user can change the configuration used by this service, and it would set/reinstantiate the configuration of the service, and then the service cannot read directly the data.

I think in some solutions, but I want to know if there's another more transparent solution, using events or something similar. Meanwhile I'll use the following, but I don't like it:

- A callback passed to service to check frequently if the configuration has changed and update if corresponds.

Comment: "Any idea" is not a question following the SO rules. Please describe the problem. Show some proof you've already done some search on the web to fix your issue yourself. And finally ask a question : "I would like to do this"

Answer (score 0):

You can write the factory class yourself to know when to only push old instance or create a new one.

For notification you can use [Spring.Messaging](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/messaging.html) for instant notification, some sort of Cache (eg. [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx) for delayed data fetching or brutal recreating Spring context. Just don't forget to remove old and register new in `ContextRegistry` in the latest option.